# ALERT! UUID=xxxx does not exist. `blkid` doesn't show output and disks not showing in `/dev/sd*/

Tags: boot

I have a Dell XPS 13 which was running Ubuntu 22.04. Since I turned it on this morning, is not booting. It drops me into a BusyBox shell...

```
BusyBox v.1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)   
Enter 'help' for list of built-in commands.  

(initramfs)
```

I've tried a bunch of commands `fsck` and `fsck -A` do nothing. I type `exit` at the prompt and get:

```
Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=441239f8-bb37-456e-806f-8b505a8e6e2e does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-91-generic root=UUID=441239f8-bb37-456e-806f-8b505a8e6e2e ro quiet splash
```

So that looks like the problem, the boot image's UUID us not found.
I also run `blkid` and get no output...

```
(initramfs) blkid
(initramfs)
```

I also try just looking around:

```
(initramfs) ls /dev/disk
ls: /dev/disk: No such file or directory
(initramfs) ls /dev/disks
ls: /dev/disks: No such file or directory
```

---

If I boot into a live session from a USB stick, the "Disks" GUI application doesn't show any drives apart from the USB stick.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0     3G  1 loop /rofs
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2    7:2    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop3    7:3    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/858
loop4    7:4    0 237.2M  1 loop /snap/firefox/2987
loop5    7:5    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop6    7:6    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/143
loop7    7:7    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop8    7:8    0 485.5M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/120
loop9    7:9    0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
loop10   7:10   0   452K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/83
sda      8:0    1   7.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    1   4.7G  0 part /cdrom
├─sda2   8:2    1   4.9M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    1   300K  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    1   2.8G  0 part /var/crash
                                 /var/log
```

---

I'm not really sure what I did before last reboot. But it's possible the kernel or boot images were updated (stupidly I didn't pay attention).

But it seems like the whole drive isn't recognised. Can anyone help?

Comment: You should try to ls /dev/disk/by-uuid and see what the correct uuid is

Comment: Ah yes, I should have said: nothing promising in `/dev`. I don't have a `/dev/disk` or any `/dev/sd*`'s.

Comment: Hmm, could you maybe include some info from your live USB stick? For example, output from `lsblk`?

Comment: Sure! I added it to the question. Only `/sda` (the usb stick itself).

Comment: What kind of drive is it (hdd/ssd/m2)? Could you possibly disconnect the drive and attempt to connect it via USB to see if it's recognized? If I were in this situation I would do everything to try to detect the drive without destroying any data on it. It is weird that it's not showing up at all.

Comment: I followed your advice. I didn't have a compatible M2 enclosure case but I happened to have another M2 drive which _was_ recognised.


On a whim I reconnected the original problematic drive and it's magically working again. Recognised and boot-able. I've not really got a clue how this happened.


My best guess is, some upstream problem with the bios which: on taking out the drive, swapping it, and reinserting did something to reset...? But this is just a total guess.


I don't know if it's possible to upgrade your suggestion to the answer but you deserve the karma for the good advice.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. If it happens again try removing and adding back the m2 drive to see if it fixes it. If it recurs though, might point to a hardware issue either with the drive or the mobo